# How do I interrupt minimax at any point?

Tags: python, python-3.x, minimax

I made a digital recreation of Chess in Python and added a Minimax algorithm to the player to play against. In order to search the maximum depth possible without wasting too much time I set a time limit and until that limit runs out I search deeper and deeper, and when time runs out I use the last finished search.

This is the algorithm (I removed some code but left in the important stuff.)

```
def play(self, current_game, depth, maxi, alpha, beta, white, limit):
        if depth <= 0 or Game.instance.isCheckmate(True) or Game.instance.isCheckmate(False) or not Game.instance.isAdequate() or Game.instance.isStalemate(True) or Game.instance.isStalemate(False):
            v = self.evaluate(current_game.board)
            return [v, None]

        board = current_game.board
        current_game.generateAllMoves(white)
        all_moves = current_game.getAllMoves()
    
        if maxi:
            best_score = float('-inf')
        else:
            best_score = float('inf')
        best_move = None

        if time.time() > limit:
            return [0, None]
            
        for move in all_moves:            
            board.makeMove(move)
            curr_score = self.play(current_game, depth - 1, not maxi, alpha, beta, not white, limit)[0]
            
            if maxi:
                if curr_score >= best_score:
                    best_score = curr_score
                    best_move = move
                alpha = max(alpha, curr_score)
            else:
                if curr_score <= best_score:
                    best_score = curr_score
                    best_move = move
                beta = min(beta, curr_score)

            board.undoMove()
            
            if beta <= alpha:
                break

        return [best_score, best_move]
```

As you can see I use a simple check to see if the current time exceeds the limit in which case I return None, however this breaks the algorith because it doesn't expect to return None, does anyone have any ideas how to do this better?
Does anyone know how to stop it when the time limit is reaches?

Answer (score 0):

To be accurate, the problem is not so much that you return `None` (as *move*), as `None` is also returned when `depth` is zero -- and it certainly isn't a problem there. The problem is that this *cut* in the traversal tree can occur when there are still main variants (i.e. top level moves) that have not been explored:

The time out may occur while only the search tree for a first top-level variant was being traversed, and so when that search comes back, the `for` loop will still try to look at other variants, but for those there will be no more depth in the search and all those calls will come back with a `None` move. These `None` moves *are* a problem, because at that top-level the move *is* important (it is not important in deeper levels of the search tree).

It is undesired that *all* available time is consumed by a first variant (top-level move). You'd want that the available time is distributed more evenly across the different variants, avoiding that a top-level recursive call must immediately return with `None`.

This can be better achieved with what is called [*iterative deepening*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search). Practically it means you first perform the minimax search (with alphabeta pruning) with depth 1, then sort the moves from best to worst, and perform the minimax search again, but now with depth 2, ...etc. Important is that the movelist is given in the order dictated by the previous run.

The nice thing here is that you will quickly get a best move (based on the depth 1 search), and incrementally that best move gets "improved" by the deeper searches. If then a time out occurs, you already have the best move, and there is nothing to return that would change that choice. All you have to do is make sure to unwind the recursion tree as soon as possible and return that best move, which is already available at that top level scope.